# Struts validation error: "Got result of null when trying to get Boolean"

Tags: java, spring, validation, struts2, struts-validation

I have action class and do validation in XML. All validation is successful except this one:

```xml
<field name="dealBoardRequestDTO.contractType">
    <field-validator type="fieldexpression">
        <param name="expression">
            <![CDATA[((dealBoardRequestDTO.contractType!=null) and
                      (dealBoardRequestDTO.contractType.size()>0) and 
                      (!dealBoardRequestDTO.contractType.contains(0))
                     )]]>
        </param>
        <message key="invalid.fieldvalue.dealBoardRequestDTO.contractType" />
    </field-validator>
</field>
```

Got the following error in the console:

> FieldExpressi W
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger warn Got
>   result of null when trying to get Boolean.

In dealBoardRequestDTO class  there is `List<Integer>` of contractType with getters and setters. If I do not use validation with the above code then all is ok and contractType is updated. Also in the action class there is a `Map<Integer, String>` for the field contractType.

Why is this error occurring?

Comment: This is just warning. If you validation not working like intended then you condition is wrong.

Comment: try to do easier, if you are searching on  a List, change size() for !isEmpty(). and contains(0) out.